# examine and prove the following statements including $\varphi$

Tags: number-theory

- How do I show that $\varphi (m)= \sum \limits_{k=1}^m \lfloor 1/(k,m)\rfloor $.
- How do I show that:
  $\sum \limits_{k=1}^m \varphi(k) \lfloor m/k \rfloor = m(m+1)/2$

I did not have any particular idea. I just thought of using the fact that they are multiplicative. Thank you in advance

Comment: The first one just requires that you note that all entries in the sum are either $1$ or $0$.

Comment: How do I do that concretely? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: Try to describe when it is $1$ and when it is $0$.

Comment: What about the 2nd one? What do you think @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: To "do that concretely" one should start with a definition of $\varphi(m)$.  If necessary do a few smallish cases like $\varphi(6)$.

Comment: I do understand that from the floor function we are supposed to get 1 or 0, but I dont understand how this could come from the definition of $\phi(n)$. @hardmath

Comment: @user123: On the left hand side we use the definition of $\varphi(m)$ to count the positive integers less than or equal to $m$ that are relatively prime to $m$.  On the right hand side we use the floor function to get $1$ each time $(k,m)=1$, i.e. $k$ is relatively prime to $m$, and $0$ otherwise, so the sum also counts how many positive integers less than or equal to $m$ are relatively prime to $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we seek to evaluate 
$$S_m = \sum_{k=1}^m \varphi(k)\lfloor m/k\rfloor$$
where $S_1=1.$

Observe that
$$S_{m+1} - S_m =
\varphi(m+1) +
\sum_{k=1}^m \varphi(k)
(\lfloor (m+1)/k\rfloor - \lfloor m/k\rfloor)
\\ = \varphi(m+1)
+ \sum_{d|m+1, d\le m} \varphi(d)
= \sum_{d|m+1} \varphi(d) = m+1.$$

This last equality can be established from
$$\sum_{d|n} \sum_{q=1, \gcd(q, n)=d}^n 1 = n.$$
But this is
$$\sum_{d|n} \sum_{p=1, \gcd(pd, n)=d}^{n/d} 1 = n
= \sum_{d|n} \sum_{p=1, \gcd(p, n/d)=1}^{n/d} 1 = 
\sum_{d|n} \varphi(n/d).$$

Therefore $$S_{m+1} = \sum_{q=1}^{m+1} q
= \frac{1}{2} (m+1)(m+2)$$
which was to be shown.

Comment: Thank you for your help! About the 1st one is examining the cases when 1 and 0 all I have to do. I mean it seems a bit trivial and I couldn't decide about how to start writing it @MarkoRiedel